# Digital clock by atmega8 with timer1 and LCD display

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, atmega

I have written code to make a digital clock using timer1 and tested with Proteus (an Arduino simulator). That program has been downloaded into an Atmega8 and interfaced to an LCD display. Seconds are being counted perfectly in 1 second duration. But when second, minutes and hours are incremented to greater than 60 I see problems. To limit those value, I have written these instruction:

```
if (second==60)
{
  second=0;
}
```

But when the seconds reach 59, the LCD shows the next second's value randomly.  For example: 59,09,19,29,39,49,59.....99,10,11,12,13,14.

My code:

```
unsigned int second=0;

unsigned int minute=0;

void init_timer1(void);

int main(void)
{
    init_timer1();
    sei();
    Init_LCD();

    while(1)
    {
        goto_position_X_Y(1,0);    //first line first position
        sprintf(lcd,"second=%d",second);
        Send_A_String(lcd);

        goto_position_X_Y(2,0);   // second line first position
        sprintf(lcd,"minute=%d",minute);
        Send_A_String(lcd);
    }
}

void init_timer1(void)
{
    TCCR1B |=(1<< CS12);      // prescaler set 256;new freq=31250;
    TCCR1B |=(1<< WGM12);
    TCNT1 =0;
    OCR1A= 3107; // 16 bit max count value 65535,
    TIMSK |=(1<< OCIE1A) ;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    second++;

    if(second==60)
    {
        second=0;
    }

    minute=minute+(second/60);

    if(minute==60)
    {
        minute=0;
    }
}
```

can you suggest me  that can  problem be occurred in lcd's program? Code:

```
Send_A_String(lcd); function of this instruction.

void  Send_A_String(unsigned char*String_data)
{
  while (*String _data>0) {
    send_A_data(*String_data++) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: please add more structure to your question. Add an empty line where you make a "mental" paragraph. Like this, it's very hard to read your question, and that makes it unlikely to get good answers. Also, the last sentence "Please...thank you" is superfluous (we're all here to help), distracts from the question and it's therefore generally discouraged to have such sentences.

Comment: If you don't show us your code, how can we tell you what's wrong with it?

Comment: Are you using timer1 interrupts?  Or are you polling timer1?  And do edit your question as suggested.  Remember, the goal is for you to make a question that other people can find when faced with a similar problem.

Comment: I have cleaned up your question.  As this appears to be an Arduino question, it may get migrated to the https://arduino.stackexchange.com forum.

Comment: `minute=minute+(second/60);` when your seconds will be 60 you reset the counter, thus minutes will always be zero as second can be max 59 when you divide it. You should put this line `minute=minute+(second/60);` before this if statement `if(second==60)`.

Comment: Hi Kaulics,.           The main problem isn't to increment the minutes .I have faced the main problem in counting second after 59th second.After 59 second  the lcd display shows second randomly.for example 59,09,19,29......99,10,11,12,13,....

Comment: Can you debug your code in some way? Either using serial connection or JTAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the LCD shows the next second's value randomly

Actually, it *isn't* shown "randomly", as you explained yourself later. Noticing that there is a pattern is important to solving this problem. Always look for patterns in your data - they are telling you *something*.

Based on your description, this is nothing to do with the values held in the actual variable `second` but it is, as you suggested later, purely a display problem. Although you've mentioned the displayed characters in a few places, I'll quote this recent comment of yours:

> i have noticed that after 59 display shows 09,19,29,39,.....89,99,10,11.....the first digit is accurate but second digit appears 9 instead of delete.

Well done! You found a pattern in the "faulty" displayed data, and that pattern contains the clue to solve this problem.

This is a classic display bug, when:

- you display some characters in a fixed position e.g. on a character LCD;
- but you don't always send *the same number of characters* to the display.

The result is that, depending on the exact behaviour of the code being used to format the data to send to the display, **there can still be some *previous* output characters left visible on the display**. In short - one character can't replace *two* characters on the display.

At the start of each minute, your output *data* for the variable `second` is: `59, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` etc.

Therefore for the first 10 seconds of each minute, you are sending only a *single* character to that fixed location on your LCD display (you describe it in the code as "first line first position"). That single character is being written to the location where the previous "tens" unit was displayed i.e. where the `5` of `59` used to be.

**That leaves the digit `9` of `59` still visible, until it is overwritten by the first output data (`10`) which has 2 digits!**

See this table showing the characters which you send to the LCD display, what you *want* (intend) it to display, and what it *actually* displays (which matches your list):

```
Data sent to display    Intended display    Actual display    Correct display
59                      59                  59                Yes
0                       00                  09                No
1                       01                  19                No
2                       02                  29                No
3                       03                  39                No
...                     ...                 ...               
8                       08                  89                No
9                       09                  99                No
10                      10                  10                Yes
11                      11                  11                Yes
...                     ...                 ...
```

I see two places where you could fix this - either:

- In your `Send_A_String()` function, test whether the input string is only a single character and add a leading `0` when that occurs. However, I would not do that, as it changes that routine from a general "display what I receive" function, into a function with specific behaviour for this program, which reduces its reusability for the future.

Or

- If your library `sprintf()` function includes the necessary functionality for "format strings" (some "minimal" `sprintf()` versions do not include this) then use:

  `sprintf(lcd,"second=%02d",second);`

  instead of your original:

  `sprintf(lcd,"second=%d",second);`

  That will cause the padding to be with the character `0` instead of spaces (`sprintf` "flags") and will cause the output to be a minimum of `2` characters (`sprintf` "width") - hence the `02` in the `sprintf()` format string.

Comment: Hi SamGibson, You are great .I changed sprintf(lcd,"second=%d",second); to sprintf(lcd,"second=%02d",second);.the display is showing my desired output.now i understood that where the  fault was occurred .I'll always be grateful to you.thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You reset the `second` counter before making the division with 60 to count the minutes. So you always add 0.

```
if(second==60)
{
    second=0;
}

minute=minute+(second/60);  // <---- This line always adds 0 because you reset the seconds before.
```

Replace the minute increment before the if statement like this:

```
minute=minute+(second/60);  // <---- Increment minutes if necessary, then reset the seconds

if(second==60)
{
    second=0;
}
```

Also declare your counters as volatile to make sure that they won't be optimized.

```
volatile unsigned int second=0;
volatile unsigned int minute=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll want to avoid doing anything "complex" in an ISR. The problem is that complexity can be hidden in rather subtle ways.

In this case, you are doing some math in your ISR, specifically, calculating `second/60`, which almost certainly involves a subroutine call into a runtime library. This library function may or may not be "interrupt safe" (the technical term is "reentrant"). If it isn't, this would explain your "random" results.

It would make much more sense to code your ISR more like this:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    second++;
    if (second==60) {
        second=0;
        minute++;
        if (minute==60) {
            minute=0;
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids all arithmetic other than increment and compare, and minimizes the number of instructions executed in the most common case (second != 60).

Comment: "calculating second/60, which almost certainly involves a subroutine call into a runtime library"  Isn't that valid only if the variable "seconds" is a floating point type?

Comment: @m.Alin: No, integer division frequently requires a library call, too. AVR has no hardware divide instruction.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. It depends if the micro has an hardware integer division instruction or not.

Comment: Hi Dave Tweed,.          The main problem isn't to increment the minutes .I have faced the main problem in counting second after 59th second.After 59 second  the display shows second randomly.for example 59,09,19,29......99,10,11,12,13,....

Comment: Does it still happen with the code that I suggested? If it does, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Dave Tweed,.    I have edited my code using your instructions.minutes are being counted accurately but only problem happened after 59 second.can you suggest me  that can  problem be occurred in lcd's program? Code:. Send_A_String(lcd); function of this instruction.void Send_A_String(unsigned char*String_data){ while (*String _data>0) { send_A_ data(*String_data++) ; } }

Comment: I would change if(second==60) to if(second >= 60).  This may not fix the OP's mystery seconds problem, but adds a bit of safety in case second somehow becomes greater than 60.

Comment: I have changed if(second==0) to if(second>=0).but same problem occurred.i have noticed that after 59 display shows 09,19,29,39,.....89,99,10,11.....the first digit is accurate but second digit appears 9 instead of delete. I mean it may be occurred because of lcd's code. Send_A_String(lcd); function of this instruction.

void  Send_A_String(unsigned char*String_data)
{
  while (*String _data>0) {
    send_A_data(*String_data++) ;
  }
}

Comment: Ah, yes, that's exactly what's going on. After you print out "0:59", which is four characters, the next thing you print out (in the same location) is "1:0", which is only three characters. This fails to blank out the last character of the previous string (the "9"), which leaves you with the "1:09" that you see. The fix is to make sure that you always produce two digits for the seconds, including a leading "0"for values less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your "seconds reset" code to

```
if(second >= 60)
{
    second=0;
    minute++;
}
```

and delete the "minute=minute+(second/60);" line - you want to increment minute every time you reset second to zero.

Comment: Hi Peter Bennett,.    The main problem isn't to increment the minutes .I have faced the main problem in counting second after 59th second.After 59 second  the display shows second randomly.for example 59,09,19,29......99,10,11,12,13,....